# Can occur match phrases that stretch across multiple lines?

Tags: regular-expressions, occur

**Q**: (how) can I use `occur` to match a phrase that
stretches over multiple lines?

Consider the following buffer:

```
Here's a line of text with the phrase "kittens and puppies".
Here's an awkward alternative: the phrase "kittens and
puppies" stretches across two lines.
Here's a false positive: "kittens and otters".
```

I'd like to identify all the locations in the buffer that contain
the phrase "kittens and puppies".  If I use `occur`, however, the
following two problems arise:

- the phrase "kittens and puppies" matches only the first line,
  and not the second/third where the phrase wraps over a line
  break.
- the phrase "kittens" (or "kittens and") also matches the false
  positive on the last line.

How, if at all, can I use `occur` to locate the relevant lines in
the buffer -- those that contain the entire phrase, or the
beginning of one that wraps across lines?  If `occur` can't do it,
is there an `occur`-like alternative that can?

Comment: The question seems unclear as posed, wrt "line", e.g., matching a line across multiple lines. Perhaps you have *visual* lines in mind here somewhere?  If so, consider clarifying that.

Comment: If you are feeling adventurous you could try `helm-swoop`. The prefix argument of it specifies how many lines it matches against.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest might be `(occur "kittens[ 
]and[ 
]puppies" nil)`

If you use occur interactively, you can insert the actual newlines with `C-q C-j`. If you use the above lisp snippet, you can replace the newlines by `\n`:
`(occur "kittens[ \n]and[ \n]puppies" nil)`

Comment: Perfect.  I was screwing up by using `\n` interactively rather than `C-q C-j` to insert the literal.